# JavaFx draw line on text area component

Tags: java, javafx

Can a set of lines be drawn on a text area component which would look like this .

I then need to be able to type in text over them . These lines also need to be erased and redrawn

[image]

Comment: Did you try anything? What didn't work for what you did?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at using the `background` property of TextArea.

```
        new TextArea().setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(myImage,BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,BackgroundPosition.CENTER,BackgroundSize.DEFAULT)));
```

This code here is assuming you can get those lines as an image.

You can find more info for backgrounds here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Background.html

If you want the background image to change and be dynamic for your current needs, you have two options.

1. Just use a Canvas for the whole project. Paint the lines onto the canvas first, and then paint the letters on top of this. This could be better as it would allow you to customize your project to however you would like it, but it would take a bit more code and thinking to do.
2. Use the TextArea, and for the BackgroundImage, use a Snapshot of another Canvas. You can use a Canvas to draw the lines however you would like, and then convert it to an image using `Snapshot`.

`WritableImage i = canvas.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);`

Then, using this image, you can use that as the background of the TextArea by using `BackgroundImage`.

Comment: I think this is a very good and innovative idea , will definitely try it. But I need the lines to be dynamic in the sense that they need to change in color and the width between them needs to change dynamically when the user click on some buttons . Can I create an image through code that will make the image reflect those changes .

Comment: @IndronilChaudhuri Yep! I added some more info on how to make background image dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Consider drawing lines on a `Pane` like so:

```
public class StageTest extends Application{

    private static final double WIDTH = 100, HEIGHT = 60;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        stage.setTitle("Test Stage");
        Label label = new Label("Some text ");
        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color:TRANSPARENT");
        label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        label.setPrefSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        Pane linesPane = getPane(label);
        StackPane root = new StackPane(linesPane, label);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private Pane getPane(Label label) {

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:WHITE");
        Line blueLine = new Line();
        blueLine.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        blueLine.startXProperty().bind(label.layoutXProperty());
        blueLine.startYProperty().bind(label.layoutYProperty().add(label.heightProperty().multiply(.333)));
        blueLine.endXProperty().bind(label.layoutXProperty().add(label.widthProperty()));
        blueLine.endYProperty().bind(label.layoutYProperty().add(label.heightProperty().multiply(.333)));

        Line redLine = new Line();
        redLine.setStroke(Color.RED);
        redLine.startXProperty().bind(label.layoutXProperty());
        redLine.startYProperty().bind(label.layoutYProperty().add(label.heightProperty().multiply(.666)));
        redLine.endXProperty().bind(label.layoutXProperty().add(label.widthProperty()));
        redLine.endYProperty().bind(label.layoutYProperty().add(label.heightProperty().multiply(.666)));

        pane.getChildren().addAll(blueLine, redLine);

        return pane;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I also need to type in text over the lines and as far as I now typing text on pane in javafx is not possible . Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It is possible. You can draw text on a pane, or better, as in this example use a component such as `Label`. The `Label` can be added to a `Pane`.